# Custom kendo grid filter with checkboxes AND input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I try to make complete custom filter for kendo grid to use both: checkboxes and input fields for filtering.

On this example:

https://dojo.telerik.com/EcUdaFeT

I added custom input fields (kendo inputs doesn't work!)

When I, for example, check inside checkboxes menu fields and select 3 products in column  'ProductName' (Chai, Chang, Aniseed Syrup) and than go to filtering inside input (for example want to see if there is product name contains "sy"), what happens is that this filtering is  now searching whole data source!

The result I want to get is Aniseed Syrup because this is the only checked value contains "sy".

Is there any way to make this to work like:

select products with product names (chai or chang or Aniseed Syrup) AND (field which contains "sy").

I know how this complex filter needs to look like - this is raw example:

```
logic:"and"
   filters:[
     {logic: 'or', filters: {field:"ProductName", operator:"eq", value:"Chai",...}},
  {logic:(this goes middle dropdown value from filter - 'and' or 'or'), filters: {field:"ProductName", operator: for example first dropdown value (contains,..), value: "sy"}}
]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to connect filter I got from checkboxes with the one I get when I use input fields filtering?

Thanks for the help!

P.S. I've already checked and read all similar questions here, but it doesn't lead me to the solution ;)

Comment: why would you want to do both? why not just do sy? its only filtering all the data within that column